# A date "is","was", or "will be" a Monday?

Tags: tenses

March 1st, 1999 *is* a Monday
March 1st, 1999 *was* a Monday

March 1st, 2099 *is* a Sunday
March 1st, 2099 *will be* a Sunday

Is there a preferred version? Do they have different meaning?

Comment: The preferred version is to use the present tense for the present, the past tense for the past, and almost always a modal verb for the future.  If you're sincere in the question you asked, you probably would get a lot out of joining our sister site, [ELL.se] (and less out of participating here).

Comment: I'd prefer using the tense appropriate for the time frame, but it's OK to use the present tense as well -- it's not like the day that a date fell on changes.

Comment: @DanBron: Sometimes I'm not sure why there are two SE sites for this since there is a lot of overlap between them, especially when it comes to apparently simple questions of language usage that have subtle issues.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what point of view you are trying to convey.

> [Date] is a [day]. / [Date] falls on a [day].

This just states a fact that a particular date occurs on a particular day, and is independent of the time of the speaker, and hence not used by the narrator in prose.

> [Date] was/{will be} a [day].

This is used by the speaker to refer to a specific date in the past/future and tell the audience what day it was or will be. This can always be used, whether in narrative prose or formal written texts.

> [Date] will be a [day].

Occasionally, people use the future tense in informal speech when they have computed something, such as "That will be five dollars.". In this case past dates would normally be described as "That would be two days ago.", but I can imagine that people can say:

> 1st March 1999 will be a Monday if we use the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: If March 1st, 1999 was a Monday, it always will be.  One could, however, say "March 1st _would have been_ a {day of the week} if we _had been using_ the Gregorian calendar [then]."

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Your version is the correct one in one context, namely when you are referring to that day itself as a past time period. However, when one is computing the date rather than referring to the day itself, people would use either the modal "would be" if it is the date of some past event. The future "will be" can fit if the computation is a purely hypothetical one. For example: "1st March 1999 will be a Monday if we use the Gregorian calender, but will be a Thursday if we use the Julian calendar."

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Obviously, if we pick a date close to today's we can have it referring to a day in the future according to the Julian calendar but a day in the past according to the Gregorian calendar, so using "will be" will be the most consistent way to talk about the date like this independent of time. Nevertheless, it would not be wrong if people use "would have been" if both reckonings put the date in the past.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Two comments up I made an incomplete sentence due to editing what I typed. I actually want to say `when one is computing the date rather than referring to the day itself, people can use the modal "would be" for dates of both past and future events.`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I failed to account for the possibility that the two calendars could now differ by that much.  I was taught that at George Wahington's birthdate, it was less than a month difference. What is the current date in Gregorian?  (Not that any of this means one whit to the OP's question.)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: It still is a meagre two weeks or so of difference now according to Wikipedia. I had to check it up just to come up with this scenario! =)

Comment: And I suppose one should refrain from saying "will be" in regard to distant future dates, because for all we know, we might change the calendar again (stardate?) by then, and there might never be, say, a March 1st, 2099.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Hahaha. Actually that's my point. We should use "will be" or "would be" when referring to what will happen if we use a certain method of computation, the simple future if we are stating a fact and the modal if we are hypothesizing about the computation method. Somehow we just don't have an English future tense that only refers to the future time. Natural language, what a pity!

Comment: That's one thing I have learned here at ELU.  English has only past and not-past. Everything else is cobbled together with auxiliaries.